# Extract MP3 Audio or Sound from PDF

Tags: pdf, audio, mp3, pdf-editor

The MP3 audios are not Attachments, they don't show up on Adobe Acrobat Pro DC's Attachments panel, they show up on the Comments panel and Adobe Reader/Acrobat can only export them to an Adobe `.fdf` file which is a data file like pdf.

Unfortunately, PDF files can't be opened as Archives, to extract files from them.

So how can I extract the MP3's? Any free Linux or Windows software that can do this easily?

I have tried these program's free trials, they either only show the comments (can't even play them) or just export to `.fdf` or not event able to show comments or only extract attachments and images:

- Ashampoo PDF Pro 2
- Code Industry Master PDF Editor
- Foxit Advanced PDF Editor
- Nitro PDF Pro
- Systools PDF Extractor

All latest versions as of 09-oct-2020

Comment: If all else fails, play them while recording audio, e.g. with VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are sound annotations. If you do not mind working with some low level PDF tools, such as XFINIUM.PDF Inspector: https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-inspector/xfinium-pdf-inspector-overview.html, you can navigate the tree of PDF objects to extract the desired stream.
You can post a sample PDF file and I can show the path you need to navigate in order to get the mp3 data.

Comment: `PDF > Root > Pages > Kids > Kids > Annots > Annots > Sound > obj` But even after saving, the binary file that is saved is not a media file and can't be played with any media player.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/pvw1s3xtnvr8ynv/New_Microsoft_Word_Document.pdf/file

Comment: The data in sound annotations is raw sound data playing at 11025 samples per second.

Comment: Were you able to successfully extract the 3 audio annotations from the PDF file I linked and play them back with VLC or your favorite media player?

Comment: Sound annotations include raw sound data, not MP3 files. The data can be extracted but it cannot be played directly with VLC or other media player.

Comment: Nice, I see, they play back weirdly with 11025 sample rate anyway.

Comment: Xfinium with no doubt is the only software that can do this. Thank you.